# PHP imap_search: UTF-8 / Non-ASCII characters on Microsoft Exchange mail servers

Tags: php, character-encoding, office365, exchange-server, imap

I want to fetch emails from `outlook.office365.com` using IMAP and PHP.

Since the most emails contain non-ASCII characters like `äöü`, I use `UTF-8` in my `imap_search()` function:

```php
imap_search($mbox_connection, 'ALL', SE_UID, "UTF-8")
```

With `UTF-8` and the search criteria `ALL` I get all emails as expected. Now, I wanted to restrict it to for example only unseen (unread) emails:

```php
imap_search($mbox_connection, 'UNSEEN', SE_UID, "UTF-8")
```

But this unfortunately causes the issue, that no emails can be found anymore - although there are unseen emails - and it also throws this PHP notice:

```
PHP Notice:  Unknown: [BADCHARSET (US-ASCII)] The specified charset is not supported. (errflg=2) in Unknown on line 0
```

Based on this notice, I've changed the charset from `UTF-8` to `US-ASCII`:

```php
imap_search($mbox_connection, 'UNSEEN', SE_UID, "US-ASCII")
```

Now, it returns all expected unseen (unread) emails.

The problem is now, that I can't search for emails with UTF-8 characters. I've for example an email with these information:

- From: Äpfel Nürnberg
- Subject: Apfel vs. Äpfel
- Body:

```
Einzahl gegen Mehrzahl.

Ein Apfel, mehrere Äpfel.
```

When I try to search for all emails with the subject "apfel" it works as expected - I can find the email:

```php
imap_search($mbox_connection, 'FROM "apfel"', SE_UID, "US-ASCII")
```

```
Trying to connect to '{outlook.office365.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX'...
Found 1 email(s)...
+------ P A R S I N G ------+
From: =?iso-8859-1?Q?=C4pfel=20N=FCrnberg?= <=?iso-8859-1?Q?=C4pfel=20N=FCrnberg?= <aepfel@nuernberg.de>>
Subject: =?iso-8859-1?Q?Apfel_vs._=C4pfel?=
```

But when I instead search for the word with the UTF-8 character (in this case `äpfel`), it does NOT find the email:

```php
imap_search($mbox_connection, 'FROM "äpfel"', SE_UID, "US-ASCII")
```

Due to this fact, I've changed back the charset from `US-ASCII` to `UTF-8`, but this only ends again at the error message `[BADCHARSET (US-ASCII)]`.

My code is very simple:

```
$mailbox = "{outlook.office365.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX";
$mailbox_username = "someone@outlook.com";
$mailbox_password = "*******";

echo "Trying to connect to '$mailbox'...\n";

$mbox_connection = imap_open($mailbox, $mailbox_username, $mailbox_password);

$mailsIds = imap_search($mbox_connection, 'SUBJECT "äpfel"', SE_UID, "UTF-8");

if(!$mailsIds) {
    echo "No emails found!\n";
    imap_close($mbox_connection);
    die();
}

echo "Found " . count($mailsIds) . " email(s)...\n";

foreach($mailsIds as $mailId) {
    echo "+------ P A R S I N G ------+\n";

    $headersRaw = imap_fetchheader($mbox_connection, $mailId, FT_UID);
    $header = imap_rfc822_parse_headers($headersRaw);

    echo "From: " . $header->from[0]->personal . " <" . $header->fromaddress . ">\n";
    echo "Subject: " . $header->subject . "\n";
}
```

I've already tried this solution, but this returns also no matching email:

```
$str = "äpfel";
$str = preg_replace('/\=\?ISO\-8859\-1\?Q\?/i', '', mb_encode_mimeheader($str, "ISO-8859-1", "Q"));
$mailsIds = imap_search($mbox_connection, 'SUBJECT "'.$str.'"', SE_UID, 'US-ASCII');
```

Any ideas, how I can search for non-ASCII characters in the email fields `From`, `Subject` and `Body` when the IMAP server does not support `UTF-8` and I also can NOT change this on server-side configuration?

This seems to be an issue with all Microsoft Exchange servers. Only those servers have this issue as far as I could found it out via Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably can't.

Exchange doesn't seem to implement charset aware searching for IMAP, and doing so is not a requirement of RFC3501 (only US-ASCII must be supported).  UTF-8 is usually supported, but this does not seem to be the case for Exchange.

You would have to switch protocols (EAS, EWS, REST services, etc.) or pull down the information, decode it yourself, and search it.  If you cache it, this isn't even too bad long term.  Since it's headers, you can get this all in one fetch.  If you need to search bodies, the case is much harder.