# PHP imap_search: Search UTF-8 / Non-ASCII characters with UTF-8 support

Tags: php, email, utf-8, character-encoding, imap

This is a similar question to this one here: [PHP imap_search: UTF-8 / Non-ASCII characters on Microsoft Exchange mail servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55977063/php-imap-search-utf-8-non-ascii-characters-on-microsoft-exchange-mail-servers)

But with the difference, that the mail server in this case supports UTF-8 searches and we also use UTF-8 in the `imap_search` function.

I have an email subject like this: `mountainguan测试`

I want to search the email with this subject or a part of the subject using this PHP code:

```php
$mailbox = "{any-mail.server.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX";
$mailbox_username = "someone@server.com";
$mailbox_password = "*******";

echo "Trying to connect to '$mailbox'...\n";

$mbox_connection = imap_open($mailbox, $mailbox_username, $mailbox_password);

$mailsIds = imap_search($mbox_connection, 'SUBJECT "mountain"', SE_UID, "UTF-8");

if(!$mailsIds) {
    echo "No emails found!\n";
    imap_close($mbox_connection);
    die();
}

echo "Found " . count($mailsIds) . " email(s)...\n";

foreach($mailsIds as $mailId) {
    echo "+------ P A R S I N G ------+\n";

    $headersRaw = imap_fetchheader($mbox_connection, $mailId, FT_UID);
    $header = imap_rfc822_parse_headers($headersRaw);

    echo "From: " . imap_utf8($header->fromaddress) . "\n";
    echo "Subject: " . imap_utf8($header->subject) . "\n";
}
```

When I search for `SUBJECT "mountain"`, it's returning the email as expected:

```sh
$ php imap-test.php
Trying to connect to '{any-mail.server.com:993/imap/ssl}'...
Found 1 email(s)...
+------ P A R S I N G ------+
From: Someone Else <someone@other-server.com>
Subject: mountainguan测试
```

When I change the search to `SUBJECT "测试"` now, it's returning this:

```sh
$ php imap-test.php
Trying to connect to '{any-mail.server.com:993/imap/ssl}'...
No emails found!
```

The same search is working via OpenSSL, so I would expect, that it's working with PHP as well:

```sh
openssl s_client -connect any-mail.server.com:993

a LOGIN someone@server.com *******
a OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ SASL-IR LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABLE IDLE SORT SORT=DISPLAY THREAD=REFERENCES THREAD=REFS THREAD=ORDEREDSUBJECT MULTIAPPEND URL-PARTIAL CATENATE UNSELECT CHILDREN NAMESPACE UIDPLUS LIST-EXTENDED I18NLEVEL=1 CONDSTORE QRESYNC ESEARCH ESORT SEARCHRES WITHIN CONTEXT=SEARCH LIST-STATUS BINARY MOVE SPECIAL-USE QUOTA] Logged in


a SELECT "inbox"
* FLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Seen \Draft unknown-0 unknown-1 $NotJunk $Forwarded)
* OK [PERMANENTFLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Seen \Draft unknown-0 unknown-1 $NotJunk $Forwarded \*)] Flags permitted.
* 9 EXISTS
* 0 RECENT
* OK [UNSEEN 9] First unseen.
* OK [UIDVALIDITY 1500057051] UIDs valid
* OK [UIDNEXT 5388] Predicted next UID
* OK [HIGHESTMODSEQ 14790] Highest
a OK [READ-WRITE] Select completed (0.000 + 0.000 secs).


a UID SEARCH SUBJECT "mountain"
* SEARCH 5387
a OK Search completed (0.001 + 0.000 secs).


a UID SEARCH SUBJECT "测试"
* SEARCH 5387
a OK Search completed (0.001 + 0.000 secs).


a UID FETCH 5387 (BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (subject date)])
* 9 FETCH (UID 5387 FLAGS (\Seen) BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (SUBJECT DATE)] {245}
Subject: =?UTF-8?Q?mountainguan=E6=B5=8B=E8=AF=95?=
Date: Sat, 4 May 2019 01:11:57 +0200

)
a OK Fetch completed (0.001 + 0.000 secs).


a logout
* BYE Logging out
a OK Logout completed (0.000 + 0.000 secs).
closed
```

What is the problem using PHP `imap_search()` here? Do I need to convert / de- or encode something of the search string to something else?

Comment: Which php version are you using?

Comment: Tested it with PHP `7.1.26`.

Comment: I tested effort Php 7.x on gmail and it worked

Comment: With my code? You can find the email with the subject `mountainguan测试` when you search for `SUBJECT 'mountain'` and `SUBJECT '测试'`? If yes: Why is it working for you and not for me? Are there any settings on the mail server or in PHP required to support this?

Comment: Yes, see this https://i.stack.imgur.com/15j0f.png. Also if it is Gmail please make sure you set conversations to off

Comment: This is strange. I've tested it with a postfix/dovecot mail server. Do you mean the conversation setting in Gmail or something else? And why does it needs to be off? Anyway: I'll test this again with the postfix/dovecot server.

Comment: What encoding is your actiual PHP script? It should also be UTF with LF line endings

Comment: `file imap-test.php` returns `PHP script, UTF-8 Unicode text`, so it should be already UTF-8 with LF line endings, right?

Comment: I'm confused. I've just tested it again with both criterias and it's always returning the expected mail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to encode `$criteria` string at `$mailsIds = imap_search($mbox_connection, 'SUBJECT "mountain"', SE_UID, "UTF-8");`

Please check encoding of your php script (imap-test.php). Probably it isn't UTF-8.
Could you convert encoding into UTF-8 and then change `$criteria` into `mountainguan测试` ?

Comment: `file imap-test.php` returns `PHP script, UTF-8 Unicode text`, so it should be already UTF-8 with LF line endings, right? Thanks for the information, that I don't need to convert the criteria.